# How to get 1-minute price data into a 15-minute chart

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I've been working on a script that uses a 15-minute time frame.  I am trying to add stop loss into my script, but it appears the script only executes every 15 minutes.  I want the stop loss to be calculated from price info based on a 1M time frame.  How do I reference 1M price changes in my 15M chart?

```
// stop loss 
// how to measure the price changes in 1 minute intervals instead of waiting for 15 minutes?
strategy.exit("Stop Loss Long", from_entry = "Buy", loss = lossAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just switched from a 15M to a 1M chart and calculated the 15-minute numbers 4 times per hour.